# How to add empty xmlns="" to struct tag for request?

Tags: go, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

Hello I'm new at golang and programming and i  have a noobish question. i couldn't find the answer on google. The soap server fails with  generated code by gowsdl. but i add this xmlns="" to auth tag its works like a charm. So how can i add this to tags not by strings replace but go idiomatic way?

Not accepted by server

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <GetCitiesRequest xmlns="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas">
        <auth>                     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<------------ fails because no xmlns=""
            <appKey>xxx</appKey>
            <appSecret>xx</appSecret>
        </auth>
    </GetCitiesRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Accepted by server

```
 <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <GetCitiesRequest xmlns="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas">
            <auth xmlns="">
                <appKey>[string]</appKey>
                <appSecret>[string]</appSecret>
            </auth>
        </GetCitiesRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

im using quick fix:

```
buffers := new(bytes.Buffer)
buffers.WriteString(strings.ReplaceAll(buffer.String(),"<auth>","<auth xmlns=\"\">"))

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", s.url, buffers)
```

what should i add struct tag to see empty xmlns="" ?

```
type GetCitiesRequest struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas GetCitiesRequest"`

    Auth *Authentication `xml:"auth,omitempty" json:"auth,omitempty"`
}
```

```
type Authentication struct {
    AppKey string `xml:"appKey,omitempty" json:"appKey,omitempty"`

    AppSecret string `xml:"appSecret,omitempty" json:"appSecret,omitempty"`
}
```

Alos i tried;

```
type Authentication struct {
   XMLName xml.Name `xml:""`

   AppKey string `xml:"appKey,omitempty" json:"appKey,omitempty"`

   AppSecret string `xml:"appSecret,omitempty" json:"appSecret,omitempty"`
}


   auth := Authentication{AppKey:"secret",AppSecret:"secret"}
   auth.XMLName.Local= "auth"
   auth.XMLName.Space = ""
```

Also i tried auth.XMLName.Space = " " empty space but xml.marshal transform it to escaped character like "&quote,#34"

I want to understand how can i do with like pro way but not noob way.
Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

---

another problem :/ not solved

tried `xml:"* categoryId"` turns out ->    `<categoryId xmlns="*">1001770</categoryId>`
yet soap api not accepting * character wants `<categoryId xmlns="">1001770</categoryId>`

```
type Authentication struct {
    Xmlns string    `xml:"xmlns,attr"  json:"-"`
    AppKey string `xml:"appKey,omitempty" json:"appKey,omitempty"`

    AppSecret string `xml:"appSecret,omitempty" json:"appSecret,omitempty"`
}

type GetSubCategoriesRequest struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas GetSubCategoriesRequest"`

    Auth *Authentication `xml:"auth,omitempty" json:"auth,omitempty"`

    CategoryId int64 `xml:"* categoryId,omitempty" json:"categoryId,omitempty"` <<<<<<<-------- i need xmlns="" 
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal

> - a field with tag "name,attr" becomes an attribute with   the given name in the XML element.
> - a field with tag ",attr" becomes an attribute with the   field name in the XML element.

```golang
type Authentication struct {
    Xmlns     string `xml:"xmlns,attr" json:"-"`
    AppKey    string `xml:"appKey,omitempty" json:"appKey,omitempty"`
    AppSecret string `xml:"appSecret,omitempty" json:"appSecret,omitempty"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iIvlUoaYvgB

Comment: Thank you sir, i spend alot of time on net to find answer. Wish i before ask this question on stackoverflow. thank you, thank, you